# PyQt4 application crashing after adding splash screen

Tags: python, pyqt4, qsplashscreen

I am trying to add a splashscreen to my PyQt4 GUI application. The code is working fine until I close the application which makes Python crash with "Python.exe has stopped working". Here's the code.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    #Splashscreen
    movie = QMovie("giphy-downsized.gif")
    splash = MovieSplashScreen(movie)
    splash.show()

    start = time.time()

    while movie.state() == QMovie.Running and time.time() < start + 10:
        app.processEvents()


    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    splash.finish(MainWindow)
    movie.stop()

    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    splash.close()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Python stopped working]

I have tried everything. The application closes perfectly if I DO NOT add splashscreen. However, python crashes after I add splashscreen and close the application. Thus, the problem lies with the objects remaining in memory or something like that but I am not able to solve it yet. Please help.

```
class MovieSplashScreen(QSplashScreen):

def __init__(self, movie, parent = None):

    movie.jumpToFrame(0)
    pixmap = QPixmap(movie.frameRect().size())

    QSplashScreen.__init__(self, pixmap)
    self.movie = movie
    self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.repaint)

def showEvent(self, event):
    self.movie.start()

def hideEvent(self, event):
    self.movie.stop()

def paintEvent(self, event):

    painter = QPainter(self)
    pixmap = self.movie.currentPixmap()
    self.setMask(pixmap.mask())
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)

def sizeHint(self):

    return self.movie.scaledSize()
```

Comment: Please read the python traceback - it makes it perfectly clear what the problem is. (PS: in future, please do not post images of console output. Always copy and paste the actual text into your question).

Comment: what is MovieSplashScreen?

Comment: You could show your complete code

Comment: Here's the MovieSplashScreen class. The complete code is more than 700 lines.